# github - Defining variables for actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to explore github actions and unable do find how to define my own variables for the workflows.
For e.g.
I want to store a `URL` as a variable which is being used throughout the workflow for getting some data.

I used gitlab previously and I use to store such variables under `Settings -> Variables` of a repo and I could able to use it in the CI pipelines.

How can I define such variables for github actions?
**Edit:**

> Main disadvantage of not having externalize variables is - I need to
> commit the workflow file every time I change variable value. For e.g.
> deployment URL changes for each environment

P.S.: I bumped on the `Settings -> Secrets` in github but I don't think this is used for such use cases as `Secrets` keep the values encrypted.

Comment: You can use environments variables in your workflows. You can find more information about them on the official documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference (As you said, secrets are also an option for critical datas).

Comment: Ok, It's the env variables with in the action script. I will work for sure. But my concern is if my workflow has 50 (just a random number) variables then the size of my script would drastically increase. That is the reason I am thinking of externalizing it to make it clean

Comment: You can also use Environment files: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files It could be practical if you have many environment variables.

Comment: @GuiFalourd, still not convinced with the solution. Environment files are almost similar to environment variables with additional redirect to the file. It's a hostile externalization!